# Mirror at most 1 value from source, then temporarily drop values until another observable emits

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I would like to combine two observables in such a way that

- I mirror at most 1 value from the source observable (same moment it arrives),
- Then ignore its subsequent values until the notifier observable emits;
- Then, I allow to mirror at most 1 more value from the source;
- After which I again ignore elements until the notifier observable emits
- etc.

Source:

```
a----a----a----a----a----a Source
------------b---------b--- Notifier
a--------------a---------a Desired result
```

The observables are infinite.

Can you please suggest a recipe to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a simple use case of the `throttle()` operator.

```
// TypeScript
let source$: Observable<any>;
let notifier$: Observable<any>;
let result$: Observable<any>;

result$ = source$.pipe(
  throttle(_=>notifier$)
);
```

Reference Link: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/throttle

Comment: Live and learn. Thanks Joshua, I didn't even think about this overload of `throttle` - somehow I keep thinking of `throttle` in terms of time intervals only.

For the record, I managed to cook something using `take(1)` and `repeatWhen(() => notifier$)`, I suspect it would have given a similar result?

Comment: I never thought of the `take()` and `repeatWhen()` combo. That should work as well.